# From Set to Map using java 8 API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm starting with java 8 stream collections and lamba expressions:

I would like to convert a set of entries to a Map.

In java 7 I would do it like this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject=e.get(EQUATION_MAPPING_KEY).getAsJsonObject();
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries=jsonObject.entrySet();
        ImmutableMap.Builder<Object, Object> builder=ImmutableMap.builder();
        for(Entry<String, JsonElement> entry:entries){
          builder.put(entry.getKey().toString(),entry.getValue().getAsBigDecimal());
        }
        put(EQUATION_MAPPING_KEY,builder.build());
```

So far I've tried this:

```
ImmutableMap<String,BigDecimal> map=entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,Entry::getValue));
```

But compiler is complaining because I cannot reference a static method from a non-static context.

How can achieve the same in java 8?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are setting `Entry::getValue` as `Map's` value which is `JsonElement` and not a `BigDecimal`. You need to convert it into `BigDecimal` in `collect`, e.g.:

```
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = jsonObject.entrySet();
ImmutableMap<String, BigDecimal> map = entries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().getAsBigDecimal()), ImmutableMap::copyOf));
```

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Added the bit to convert the result to `ImmutableMap`